# Use command output as argument in watch command

Tags: bash, command-substitution, watch

I have a watch on

```
jq -r '.' $(ls -t | head -1)"
```

The goal is to apply "jq -r '.'" to the most recently modified file in directory.
Unfortunately, the command used to know the last modified file is evaluated when watch is launched, but not at refresh.
How should i write it, so that all of the command is reevaluated at each refresh ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the command in single quotes it will be expanded on each cycle of watch rather than when you run the watch command, for example:

```
watch echo $(date)

watch 'echo $(date)'
```

The first command will print the original date over and over, the second command will run the `date` on each cycle and print a different date.

This is because you are passing the literal string `echo $(date)` to the watch command, which runs it each cycle and echos the correct date. If you don't use quotes, the shell will expand the `$(date)` and replace it with the output of the date command and pass that to `watch`, so it will print the same output over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your command is that when you execute

```bash
watch jq -r '.' "$(ls -t | head -1)"
```

... then the command substitution is executed once, as part of evaluating the command line arguments for the `watch` command.

You must stop the current shell from evaluating the command substitution when launching `watch` to have `watch` run a command that evaluates the substitution each time the command is run.

You can do that with

```bash
watch 'jq -r . "$(ls -t | head -1)"'
```

---

The most recently modified regular file (possibly symbolically linked) in a directory is given by the filename globbing pattern `*(.om[1])` in the `zsh` shell.  The parenthesis qualifies the way that the preceding `*` matches names; The dot selects exclusively regular files (possibly symbolically linked), `om` orders (`o`) by last-modified timestamp (`m`), and `[1]` picks out the first name only from the generated list.

Another way to write your command would therefore be

```bash
watch -x zsh -c 'jq . *(.om[1])'
```

Here, the `-x` causes `watch` to `exec` the given command instead of running it with `sh -c`.